# How to use ng-class for array of buttons for giving a separate condition to each button

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a simple problem statement. I have to take arrays of 3 buttons and on the click of every button the background of the page should change. This should be done in pure angular-typescript (javascript functions cannot be used). I just know that I have to use ng-class for giving conditions to the button but I am not sure how. I have successfully made an array of three buttons but I am stuck now. Please help with a solution. Below is my component.ts code

```
buttons = [
{
  name: 'Red',
  id: 'btn1'
},
{
  name: 'Green',
  id: 'btn2'
},
{
  name: 'Blue',
  id: 'btn3'
}
];

getColor(id) {
switch (id) {
  case 'btn1':
    return 'red';
  case 'btn2':
    return 'green';
  case 'btn3':
    return 'blue';
}
}
```

Below is the html code which I tried.

```
<div *ngFor="let button of buttons">
  <button [ngStyle]="{'background-color':getColor(button.id)}">
  {{ button.name }}</button>
</div>
```

I used ng-style but that did not work as expected. Please suggest me the solution using ng-class.

Comment: Your code works fine https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-style-example1?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Your code is fine but you want to change the page color so I created one demo which changes the div color on click of the particular button. see this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vjbwsu?embed=1

Comment: @AmitChigadani yes but I need to change the background of the whole page on click of every button

Comment: Thanks for the help but actually I needed to change the background of the whole page that too using ng-class..can you help me with that @SnehaPawar

Comment: If you want to do it using `ng-class`, then you have to either write css for each class, or use `Renderer2` to do it from the component.

Answer (score 0):

Update your HTML page as below

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'background-color': color}">
    <hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
     <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)
     </p>
    <div *ngFor="let button of buttons">
     <button (click)="color=button.name" >
    {{ button.name }}</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sneha, change your button (click) for some like (click)="color=button.name"

Comment: Yes, this is also another option to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can directly provide `button.name` in your inline css

```
<div *ngFor="let button of buttons">
  <button [ngStyle]="{'background-color': button.name}">
  {{ button.name }}</button>
</div>
```

you acn also check on link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ufnq8p?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0):

> Working Demo for your use case
>   https://stackblitz.com/edit/create-xgn8sa?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts